# Trying to get links on iPhone to work

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iphone

I'm using HTML5 and ive got a weird issue, I've started making a site but as I am testing the site i found that on a certain page links on iPhone do not seem to work. The HTML for it:

```
<a href="link">
   <div>
       <img src="img" />
   </div>
</a>
```

For css ive tried a few things, increasing the z-index of the a tags, adding a height and width. Heres the sample css for it too:

```
a {
   display:block;
   z-index:999;
   height:200px;
   width:300px;
}
```

Also tried adding some javascript, i found from another stackover question:

```
$(function () {          
        IS_IPAD = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
        IS_IPHONE = (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) != null) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) != null);

        if (IS_IPAD || IS_IPHONE) {

            $('a').on('click touchend', function () {
                var links = $(this).attr('href');
                window.open.replace(links); // opens in new window as requested
                return false; // prevent anchor click    
            });
        }
    });
```

But still no luck

**UPDATE**
The issue seems to be solved on the iphone 5s but not on the iphone 5c

**UPDATE**
It seemed to be related to the newest update to the apple iphone software

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="hovytech.github.io">
    <img src="img.png"></img>
</a>
```

---

**OR**

```
<img src="image.png" onClick="javascript:location.href='http://hovytech.github.io'"></img>
```

---

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zvdu88da/1/)

Comment: it seems to be only affecting the iPhone 5c whilst its not an issue on the iPhone 5s. I've cleared my cache on both devices but there is still an issue on the 5c

Comment: Try it on a different iPhone 5C, cause maybe it might be just your iPhone. My dad has one and I have a similar method of a link and it works on his.

Comment: nope same issue, for some reason its working on some iphone 5s and not on other 5s and 5c

Comment: Wow that's **really** weird

Comment: What are you using to host it

Comment: Looking more closely at the issue the iphone 5s it does work on ios is 8.1.3 whilst iphone 5c is 8.4.1

Comment: It's then probably a bug.

Comment: There is a way in javascript if you're interested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88573/discussion-between-jsg-and-hovytech).

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function openLink() {
                //Replace current window
                //window.open("http://hovytech.github.io", "_self");
                //Open new window
                window.open("http://hovytech.github.io", "_blank");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="http://hovytech.github.io/Images/HovyTech.png" width="self" height="100px" onclick="openLink()"></img>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Hope this method works for you.